# simple webform PHP script - it doesn't work

Tags: php, webforms

I would like the Php script print to the screen all the values it gets from the html page.

This is the HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="rect.php" method="post">
        <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br />
        <label>Family Name:</label><input type="text" name="family"><br />
        <label>Age:</label><input type="text" name="age"><br />
        <input type="button" value="Print">
    </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

//And this is the PHP code:

```
    <?php 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$family_name = $_REQUEST['family'];
$age = $_REQUEST['age'];

print $name.$family_name.$age;
?>
```

Comment: You already gave the answer you wanted, what do you need exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to print the values after the form has been submitted ?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: Use `$_POST`. Using `$_REQUEST` is bad practice.

```
<?php 
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $family_name = $_POST['family'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   print $name.$family_name.$age;
?>
```

---

And your button doesn't submit. Make it this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Print">
```

Comment: Why would that fix it? The $_POST variables should be present in $_REQUEST too.

Answer (score 2):

The $_REQUEST should work, your button however is a useless one.

```
    <input type="button" value="Print">
```

should be

```
    <input type="submit" value="Print">
```

And that should do the trick :)

Comment: Thank you for reply :)
but when I change it to submit it ask me to save the file. but I would like it to print it to the screen.

Comment: Because your enctype in the form-tag is useless. Remove it completely, or change it to "enctype="text/plain"" because you're not trying to upload stuff, you're trying to sent text.

Comment: I removed it and the button is "submit" now... but still, it try to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<input type="button" value="Print">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="Print">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the enctype if you're just sending text to the PHP form.

Your button must be type="submit"

and you should use $_POST since clearly you used it for the form.